# Does Samsung galaxy 7 turn itself on once dies and plugged up to chrger?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

Will my Samsung galaxy 7 turn itself on once plugged into wall, or do I have to turn it on myself ?

Comment: if device got turned off itself, because of low battery, plug into wall will be good. You need to turn on the device after charging for sometime.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything in the user guide one way or another but I have a Galaxy S7 myself and I tested this several times.  I found that you do have to turn the phone on once it has started charging.  It will not turn itself on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually turn the phone on. If you turn the phone on immediately, you will only have a few seconds of use before it turns itself off again. You have to wait a few minutes for the battery to get to 1 or 2% before it will stay on while charging.